# How to update $scope outside the modal bootstrap in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope

I have `$scope.users` which displays some items.

When I click on one of these items, a modal appears to confirm the deletion.
The query to delete works great, but my `$scope.users` is not updated in the view... 
I think it's because the `$scope.users` is not is the same controller.

What is the solution to update scope ? (without use the $rootscope) ?

```
app.controller('backController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope','MyFunctions', '$location', '$modal',
  function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, MyFunctions, $location, $modal) {
    MyFunctions.getUsers().then(function (data) {
      $scope.users = data;
    });

    $scope.openModalDeleteUser = function (user) {
      $scope.user = user;
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'template/app/modalDeleteUser.html',
        controller: 'modalDeleteUserController',
        scope: $scope,
      });
    };

}]);


app.controller('modalDeleteUserController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'MyFunctions',
  function ($scope, $modalInstance, MyFunctions) {

    $scope.delete = function(){
      var data = {};
      data['action'] = 'delete_user';     
      MyFunctions.updateData(data).then(function (response){
        MyFunctions.getUsers().then(function (data) {
          $scope.users = data;
          console.log($scope.users); // Data retrieve is OK, but not updated in the view
        });
      });
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }  

    $scope.cancel = function () {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
MyFunctions.getUsers().then(function (data) {
      $scope.users.length = 0; //empty the current array
      $scope.users.push.apply($scope.users,data); //push the data array to current array.
});
```

**Explanation**:

The $scope in your `modalDeleteUserController` is **child scope** of your `backController` scope. When you assign `$scope.users = data;`, it creates a new property on your child scope without updating the parent scope. The current solution clears data from the inherited property and add new data to it so that the parent scope is updated.

From [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/):

> scope - a scope instance to be used for the modal's content (actually
>   the $modal service is going to create a child scope of a provided
>   scope). Defaults to $rootScope

Another solution is declaring a property to *hang* your data:

```
app.controller('backController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope','MyFunctions', '$location', '$modal',
  function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, MyFunctions, $location, $modal) {
    $scope.data = {};//declare a property
    MyFunctions.getUsers().then(function (data) {
      $scope.data.users = data; //store users as a property of this property
    });
```

And then you can just use `$scope.data.users = data;` in your modal `modalDeleteUserController`

Note: Remember to update your template bindings to add this `.data` prefixes.

Comment: lol, OMG ! Why is this work ? Great answer but I don't understand why. Can you explain please ?

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer of Nikolas seems the same, but it doesn't work. I don't understand why.

Comment: @Steffi: no, the problem has nothing to do with $apply. $apply is already called by angular, calling it again may throw exception. The main problem is `it creates a new property on your child scope without updating the parent scope`

Comment: I think Khanh TOs answer is correct. Mine is wrong. I will delete mine, as it is not working.

Comment: @Steffi: be aware that `apply` in my answer is not the same as `$scope.$apply`.

Comment: @Steffi:also take a look at this for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: @Steffi: I added 1 more solution to this problem.

Comment: @KhanhTO Thank you. I think I get it. But I try with another scope it doesn't work. I have `$scope.tab = 1` inside controller A and I would like to update `$scope.tab` with the value `2`. I try apply() but I have an error... `$scope.tab = 2` doesn't wor, `$scope.tab.apply($scope.tab, 2)` doesn't work and `$scope.apply(function(){ $scope.tab = 2; })`. Your example only works with array ?

Comment: @Steffi: `apply()` is a method of a function. You could have a look at the link? In your case, you're using a value type, not reference type. You need to try the second approach.